# Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized on hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am learning Hibernate and I dont understand why am I getting this error launching program:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:172)
at net.codejava.hibernate.VueloManager.setup(VueloManager.java:15)
at net.codejava.hibernate.VueloManager.main(VueloManager.java:54)

`hibernate.cfg.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property
                name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property
                name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/vuelos_lite</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <mapping class="net.codejava.hibernate.Vuelo" />
        <mapping class="net.codejava.hibernate.Pasajero" />
        <mapping class="net.codejava.hibernate.Pasaje" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

VueloManager class. This is the main class of the program:

```
public class VueloManager {
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected void setup() {
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
        try {
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }
    protected void read() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        String identificadorId = "BRU-2222";
        Vuelo vuelo = session.get(Vuelo.class, identificadorId);

        System.out.println("Id: " + vuelo.getIdentificador());
        System.out.println("Fecha: " + vuelo.getDate());
        System.out.println("Tipo Vuelo: " + vuelo.getTipo_vuelo());

        exit();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VueloManager manager = new VueloManager();

        manager.setup();
        //manager.read();
        manager.exit();
    }
}
```

I have checked hibernate.cfg.xml connections and all is fine.

Comment: Does the database `vuelos_lite` already exist? If not, that could cause the mentioned error.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose yes the database vuelos_lite already exist